# Knockout popover bindings for checklist

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to bind the values from database to popover checkbox list using knockout Js.Please help.Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.valuesForCheckBoxList = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.init = function () {
        $.get("... url for get data from database ...", function (data) {
            self.valuesForCheckBoxList(data);
        });
    };
    self.init();
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

And if returned data will be looked like this: `[{Id: 1, Name: "n1"}, {Id: 2, Name: "n2"}]`, you could write folowing html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: valuesForCheckBoxList">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $root.valuesForCheckBoxList, value: Id" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

For configure you request more specifically you could read this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ page.
ko.observableArray: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html
checkbox bindings: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html